# ¿Como enviar dos variables con ajax a php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Quisiera saber como enviar dos variables en el tag de data,ya que,quiero actualizar el registro, básicamente cuando presiono el boton de editar un registro me abre un popup , y hay le doy al boton de actualizar, lo que no comprendo es como enviar esta informacion al php y como hago la validación si llego o no dicha información y devuelva el resultado , intente con esto :

(Editado)

```html
$(".btn-edit").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('product'); //Obtengo el registro escogido guardando el id verificador
    alert(id)

      $(".modaleditar").fadeIn(); // Muestro el modal
      $(".form-edit").submit(function(o){ // Envio la información al presionar el btn submit
          o.preventDefault(); //Evito la recarga de pagina
          var para = $(this).serialize(); // Guardo la información del formulario "form-edit" con serialize para enviarlo por POST
          $.ajax({ // Metodo ajax
              url:"process/prueba.php", // Envio de datos
              type: "POST", //Metodo de envio
              data:{para:para,id:id}, // Envio el id y la información del formulario guardado en la variable "para" hacia update.php
              success: function(response){
                console.log(response)

              
             
              }
          })
      })
})
```

Aqui esta el codigo de recibo de php

```html
<?php

if (isset($_POST)) {
    $id = $_POST["id"];
    $info = $_POST["para"];
    echo $info;
    echo $id;
} else {

    echo  "No se recibio la información";
}
```

Y aqui esta el resultado [image: Resultado]

Comment: testea poniendo algo en duro en el update, ponle un texto fuera de php para ver que responde y revisa las peticiones http a traves de la consola para ver que responde

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hay muchas formas esta es solamente una de ellas:

```js
$(".edit_register").click(function(e){ //Al presionar el btn se ejecuta el siguiente codigo
    e.preventDefault();
    var registro = $(this).attr('product'); // Esta variable contiene el id identificador al presionar el registro pertinente para editarlo

      $(".modaleditar").fadeIn(); // Me muestra el popup

    $(".formulario-actualizar").submit(function(o){ //Al presionar el boton actualizar del popup que me envie los datos tanto el id identificador como la información del formulario
      o.preventDefault();
      let data=$(".formulario-actualizar").serialize()+'&id='+registro;
      console.error('data',data);
        $.ajax({
            url: "process/update.php",
            type: "POST", 
            async:true,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: data,   
    }).done(function(data) {
        // Un uso común de JSON es intercambiar datos desde un servidor web
        // JSON.parse; Convertimos los datos en un objeto JavaScript. 
        let respuesta = JSON.parse(data);
            
    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.error('status ',textStatus);
    }) 
  
 });
   
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 

<div class=" btn btn-info edit_register" product="1">popup</div>


<div class="card modaleditar" style="display:none">
  <div class="card-header">
    Editar
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <form class="formulario-actualizar">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email</label>
          <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" value="correo@dominio.com">
          <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">coloque aqui su mail.</small>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="">Usuario</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="usuario" value="usuario">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">enviar</button>
      </form>

  </div>
</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

así quedaría recibes por `$_POST['id']`

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135661/discussion-on-answer-by-john-como-enviar-dos-variables-con-ajax-a-php).